# Binding data to gridview not showing grid asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a datagrid I am trying to populate with my query. The code below works in my winform app and I didn't think that asp and c# binding data would be that different. I have seen people use Dataset and SqlCommand but it didn't seem relevant since it worked in my winform app. How can I change this to work  for ASP gridview? Thank you for your time and help.

Method for getting the data: It should return two columns of data.

```
StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
sqlString.Append("SELECT DISTINCT o.SALES_NUMBER AS [Sales Number], ");
sqlString.Append("d.DropTime AS [Drop Time] ");
sqlString.Append("FROM [L\\sqlexpress].F_MSS.dbo.Order_Detail o ");
sqlString.Append("FULL OUTER JOIN ");
sqlString.Append("[COMMAND\\sqlexpress].Practiceville.dbo.DropTime d ");
sqlString.Append("ON o.SALES_NUMBER = d.SalesONumber ");
sqlString.Append("Where o.SALES_NUMBER IS NOT NULL ");
sqlString.Append("Order by o.SALES_NUMBER ");

DataTable dt = null;

SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["Connection"].ToString());

        try
        {//set data source
            dt = DBHelper.executeDataTable(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                dropGridView.DataSource = dt;
            }

            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to DataBind:

```
dropGridView.DataSource = dt;
dropGridView.DataBind();
```